# How to add launch images to LaunchScreenStoryboard?

Tags: ios

To support iPad split functionality of iOS9 I have to use LaunchScreen Storyboard. But how can i add launch images to LaunchStoryBoard imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add launch screen images using image.xcassets.

1. Open your Xcdoe.
2. Find your image.xcassets on left hand side.
3. In that see "+" button. Click on it. You find New Launch Image.
4. Select "New Launch Image" option.
5. Then add all your launch images in it.

Comment: I have to use launch Images in LaunchScreen StoryBoard. How can i assign launch image to imageview?

Comment: Till i know you don't need to do any code. Just keep image in Launch Image and your work is done.

Comment: I did the same what you told but in iPad its not taking correct image for Portrait mode and in iPhone its not taking correct image for landscape mode. Why it is so ?

Comment: i added all launch images in assetcatalog and added imageview in LaunchScreen.xib. But its not taking correct image for iPad Portrait mode. Please help. Its very urgent

Comment: In  image.xcassets  create launch Image and keep all images in it according pixel. Then go to General Tab -> App icon and launch image -> Launch image Source -> Select your launch image of image.xcassets in that.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly add images in image.xcassets and then create image view in Launchscreen storyboard. from there you can access.